# Flask: Utilize User Input

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I'm trying to allow the user to pick between a few different videos in a folder and play which one they want by utilizing their input.

Current Code:

```
@app.route('/AAR/')
def aar():
    path = Path().absolute()
    print(path)
    path = str(path) + r"\static\trainings"
    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    temp = []
    for dir in dirs:
        temp.append({'name': dir})

    return render_template('aar.html', data=temp, selection = "hi")

@app.route("/AAR/" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    select = request.form.get('comp_select')
    print(select)
    return render_template('aar.html', selection = select)
```

HTML:

```
{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block body %}
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/style.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Trainings</h1>
        <hr>
        <form class="form-inline" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Please select</span>
                      <select name="comp_select" class="selectpicker form-control">
                        {% for o in data %}
                        <option value="{{ o.name }}">{{ o.name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        <hr>

    </center>
</body>

<div id="load3" class="load3">
  <title>Video Example</title>
  <h2>Video Replay Test</h2>
  <h2>{{ selection }}</h2>
  <video width=500 height="500" controls>
    <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='trainings/{{ selection }}')}}" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My thought process here was that I could retrieve the user selection of a video name (works correctly) and then simply re-render the page and use the name of the user selected video in the `src` to load up the video, but so far when I click "Go" nothing happens. It is successfully printing to console the user selection, but nothing else seems to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested parentheses. This is not effective because you are already starting a Jinja statement with the outer two curly braces.

Try to form the URL by concatenation.

```
<source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='trainings/' + selection) }}" type="video/mp4">
```

---

In order to change the page without it being re-rendered, the use of JavaScript is required.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template
)
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/AAR/')
def aar():
    videos = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'trainings'))
    return render_template('aar.html', **locals())
```

After intercepting the submit event and suppressing the default behavior of the form, the selected value can be queried and the url can be assigned to the src attribute of the video.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Videos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Trainings</h1>
        <hr />
        <form name="video-form" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Please select</span>
                    <select name="comp_select" class="selectpicker form-control">
                        {% for video in videos %}
                        <option value="{{ video }}">{{ video }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </center>
    <hr />
    <div id="load3" class="load3">
        <h2>Video Replay</h2>
        <video 
            id="video-preview" 
            controls 
            src="{{ url_for('static', filename='trainings/' + videos[0]) }}" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            // Register a listener for submit events.
            const form = document.querySelector('form[name="video-form"]');
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                // Suppress the default behavior of the form.
                event.preventDefault();

                // Get the selected value.
                const videoSrc = this.comp_select.value;
                const video = document.getElementById('video-preview');
                // Assign the new URL to the attribute.
                video.setAttribute('src', `/static/trainings/${encodeURIComponent(videoSrc)}`);
            });
        })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahhh okay that makes sense. I didn't know you could do that.  I think that was probably one of the issues, but when I hit "Go" it successfully sends the chosen video name string back, but it's still like the page isn't being re-rendered with the chosen video to play.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation of how to play the videos without reloading the page.

Comment: So cool! I just started my flask journey like a week ago, so seeing how quickly you came up with a solution here was pretty cool to see. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thank you. A little practice and I think you'll have the experience too.